# Can I pray Salat ul-Layl once Faj'r time starts?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, time, tahajjud

The **timing of Faj'r here starts from 4:25.The Athan in my area for Faj'r is at 4:45** The **Jama'ah is currently at 5:10.**

I wake up at 4:00 and generally take about 15 minutes more or less (actually not less, always more ;_;) to get up, make wudu, clean up, brush my teeth and stuff. 
**I pray Tahajjud right after that, I start around 4:15-4:20. Since 5 minutes is not enough to complete my Salat ul-Layl, I have to pray it within the Faj'r time.** And then go to the Masjid at 4:55 and pray my Sunnah and Fard prayer of Faj'r there. **Is it okay to do so, I mean can I pray Salat ul-Layl if the Faj'r time starts?**
I have read some hadiths and came to know that Salat ul-Layl can be prayed at any time of the night until dawn. It is best to pray in the last third of the night. The start of Faj'r time doesn't indicate the dawn though, right? I am a bit confused whether it is valid or not. Can anyone clarify me on this issue?

*Jazak Allahu Khayran.*

Comment: @Medi1Saif, The night ends when the dawn begins. And according to Prophet Muhammad (SAW) the dawn begins when the first line of light can be seen on the horizon. [see](http://www.islamandquran.org/fatwas/time-of-dawn-prayer.html)

Comment: @Medi1Saif, And although the Faj'r time here starts at 4:25, the dawn does not come up until 4:50-5:00. So, that pretty much contradicts your statement.
It has been narrated in Hadith (look it up yourself) that Prophet (SAW) said it can be prayed from any time from Isha'a up until the dawn time or the time when the first light of light can be seen on the horizon. But it is best to pray it in last 1/3 of night. 

There are other statements that suggest the time of Salat ul-Layl ends when the Athan for Faj'r prayer is heard. [see](http://www.duas.org/tahajjud.htm)

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Others like you claim the time ends when Faj'r time starts. Each statement varies from one another. And that is exactly why I asked the question here. So you see, stating the meaning of Al-Lail doesn't really help nor does it answer my question. Your comment adds literally nothing to my question. 
And why would I explain to you what tahiyyat al-masjid is, exactly? What does it have to do with this question? There is an option to ask questions in this site, look it up buddy.

Comment: From my location, 3 athans can be heard. Sometimes simultaneously other times it gets a few seconds delayed. But it does not have anything to do with the question. Why are you querying irrelevant things in the comment thread mate? If you do not have an answer to provide then move along. I am here seeking help not to start a pointless debate which is exactly what you are looking for as it seems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76090/discussion-between-yosef-and-medi1saif).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Arabic fatwa on islamweb #[36821](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/36821) it is permissible to continue praying the night prayer (salat al-Lail) after the adhan of fajr (the first adhan if performed at your place or the call on the sixth أذان السدس) and go on praying until the adhan of sobh (true fajr: which is referred to as the redness of the dawn or when the white shades moves into yellow and a light right color). The practice of two adhans with a time gap is addressed in [this sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/44).
This time indeed is a highly recommended time for worship, as Allah says:

> Establish prayer at the decline of the sun [from its meridian] until the darkness of the night and [also] the Qur'an of dawn. Indeed, the recitation of dawn is ever witnessed. ([17:78](http://legacy.quran.com/17/78))

and in the sunnah you ma read this hadith qudsi:

> Our Lord, the Blessed and the Exalted, descends every night to the lowest heaven when one-third of the latter part of the night is left, and says: Who supplicates Me so that I may answer him? Who asks Me so that I may give to him? Who asks Me forgiveness so that I may forgive him? ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/201))

Sheikh ibn abi Zayd al-Qayrawani says in his ar-Risala:

> If you normally pray at the end of the night but oversleep, you can
> still do your night prayers overlapping the time of Fajr up to when it
> begins to get light. (Source: [Muwatta.com](http://www.muwatta.com/ebooks/english/risala_ibn_abi_zayd.pdf) pdf: p195 10.11j Oversleeping)

Therefore according to the linked fatwa it is permissible to continue praying salat al-Lail and witr until right before you may move to pray fajr and sobh (fjar fard prayer).

More over you may even be allowed to pray it as a qada' if you missed it (with different opinions according madhhabs however you could at least do qada' for witr until before noon).

Here's a similar fatwa available in English islamqa #[65692](https://islamqa.info/en/65692).

Comment: Jazak Allahu Khayran, mate <3