# Huge difference between timing of Azan-e-Fajir in normal days and in Ramadan?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

As we usually see in Pakistan that In normal days Azan-e-Fajir is recited about 4:30am-5:00am in summers and in winters it ranging 5:45am - 6:00am depending upon the location. But when Ramadan comes, timing of Azan-e-Fajir changes and move back mininum one hour from normal days.Why a huge difference occur in one day?
Why in one day this time moves back too fast?

### why?What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me, you can't expect that other people may explain what happens in a country they don't know. But maybe reading the answer of this post [Can I pray salat  ul layl once fajr time satrts](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47514/can-i-pray-salat-ul-layl-once-fajr-time-starts) might help you.

Comment: in that case only the people who are from that country should answer. I find nothing wrong with the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time for Fajr is from dawn till sunrise.

Since fasting must begin at dawn, during Ramazan they hold the congregation closer to its starting time, it is convenient.

During normal days they delay it while remaining within the time limits, and this is a practice of the Hanafi madhab.

> " ويستحب الإسفار بالفجر " لقوله عليه الصلاة والسلام " أسفروا بالفجر فإنه أعظم للأجر "

> Isfar (appearance of whiteness) is recommended for the fajr prayer,
> due to the words of the Prophet (God bless him and grant him peace),
> "Delay fajr till whiteness for it fetches the maximum reward."

> <sup>—   [الهداية في شرح بداية المبتدي](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=215&idto=223&bk_no=9&ID=17)  ; [[English translation](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n67/mode/2up)]</sup>